# Help on how to use a style provided by biblatex-archaeology

Tags: biblatex

The [biblatex-archaeology](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-archaeology) biblatex package provides a number of `biblatex` styles.

I can for instance use:

```
\usepackage[style=ufg-muenster-inline]{biblatex}
```

but when I select an additional style provided by the package it fails

```
\usepackage[style=ufg-Antiquity]{biblatex}
```

> Package biblatex Error: Style 'ufg-Antiquity' not found.

How can I have access to these dozens of additional styles?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where does it say that the package provides that style? The only mention of `ufg-Antiquity` in the manual that I found is in the list of predefined journal name strings. That list is not a list of provided styles. As far as I can see all provided styles are listed in §2.1.1 and §2.1.2. There are three `ufg` styles, but none is `ufg-Antiquity`.

Comment: Thank you moewe. The fact that the style name and the strings started by "ufg-" confused me.

Comment: Does the package provide the elements to generate a style that I could use for other journal such as Antiquity, to build myself the **ufg-Antiquity** style?

Comment: Possibly. But possibly it would be easier to start from one of the standard styles. In my experience styles that implement very idiosyncratic guidelines can be hard to modify and use for other styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles provided by the `biblatex-archaeology` bundle are listed in  §2.1.1 *Styles > Generic Styles* and §2.1.2 *Styles > User styles* of the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-archaeology/biblatex-archaeology.pdf).

`ufg-Antiquity` is not amongst the list of implemented styles. The manual mentions that the bundle defines a predefined journal name string called `ufg-Antiquity`, but that does not imply that there is a matching style.